# Calling object functions with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a simple node.js websocket server and I want to be able to send a request from a client to the server and have it just take care of things (nothing that could cause harm). Ideally the client will pass the server an object with 2 variables, one of them for the object and the other for the specific function in that object to call. Something like this:

```js
var callObject = {
  'obj': 'testObject',
  'func':'testFunc'
}

var testObject = {
  func: function(){
    alert('it worked');
  }
}

// I would expect to be able to call it with sometihng like.
console.log( window[callObject.obj] );
console.log( window[callObject.obj][callObject.func] );
```

I tried calling it with global (since node.js doesn't uses it instead of a browsers window) but it won't work, it always tells me that it can't find callObject.func of undefined. If I call a console.log on callObject.obj it shows the objects variable, as a string, as expected. If run a console.log on the object itself I get the object back.

I'm guessing this is something rather simple, but my Google-fu has failed me.

Comment: There's no straight forwards way for this to work; no `global` like `window`. You'll need to write more code: like a switch statement on `callObject.obj` or keep all the objects you might call within another object.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to resist that pattern and not have client code pick any function to call. If you are not careful you have built yourself a nice large security hole. Especially if you are considering using `eval`.

Instead have a more explicit mapping between data sent by the client and server code. (Similar to what routes in express what give you).

You might have something like this

```
const commands = { doSomething() { ... } );

// Then you should be able to say:
let clientCommand = 'doSomething'; // from client
commands[clientCommand](param);
```

This should be pretty close to what you want to achieve.
Just make sure `doSomething` validates any parameters passed in.

For two levels of indirection:

```
const commandMap = { room: { join() { ...} }, chat: { add() { ... } }};
// note this is ES6 syntax

let clientCmd = 'room';
let clientFn = 'join';

commandMap[clientCmd][clientFn]();
```

I think you might just have to find the right place to put the command map. Show your web socket handler code.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, just 2 levels (so I can group the functions by what they do: room, chat, logic ect). The contents of the callObject object are checked (both for that they exist and that they are in the objects I allow) before calling, or attempting to call. I can't actually check functions because I can't call them.

And I really don't want to use eval for this, since it is something that could be exploited with a more annoying check process.